# How to check optimality of conic optimization problem

Tags: optimality-conditions, semidefinite-programming, conic-optimization

I'm trying to solve this problem, but I'm not sure if it is possible to check the optimality of this problem.

$$\min_{K,L} \quad Tr(L^\top L)\qquad\\
\text{s.t.} \quad K^\top L = A^\top Q\\
\qquad \qquad \qquad Q + A^\top Q A - K^\top K \succeq 0\\
\quad \quad Q - L^\top L \succeq 0$$

where A,Q are real $n\times n$ matrix, and Q is PD. Is it possible to generate optimal solution (K,L) as functions of (A,Q)? Additionally, is there conditions of solutions to guarantee the optimality of certain solution?

Comment: Section 5.5 of https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf

Comment: Thanks. But due to the first equality constraint, isn't this problem nonconvex and the KKT conditions do not guarantee the global optimality?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The extended KKT conditions are necessary, but not sufficient in this case.